# Outer Query OrderBy does not depends on Inner Query's Resultset

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, sql-order-by

I am not having deep knowledge of SQL execution order.

When I Execute a Query

```
select top 2 * from Configuration
```

It Gives me

```
ABC1,100,Data001    
ABC2,200,Data002
```

When I Execute a Query

```
select top 2 * from Configuration order by 1 desc
```

It Gives me

```
XYZ1,400,Data100    
XYZ2,300,Data099
```

When I Execute a Query

```
select * from (select top 2 * from Configuration) as a order by 1 desc
```

It gives me

```
XYZ1,400,Data100    
XYZ2,300,Data099
```

---

My problem is why i am getting

```
XYZ1,400,Data100    
XYZ2,300,Data099
```

as output instead

```
ABC1,100,Data001    
ABC2,200,Data002
```

As per my knowledge Inner Query Will Return two rows to Outer Query.
Outer Query Will process those two rows with

```
From->Where->group by->having->Select->Order by
```

order of Execution and Will give output as two rows which I mentioned as expected. But Outer Query's order by is affecting on whole table of Inner Query.

Please comment where I am making mistake.

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?  I'm using SQL Server and the result is as expected `ABC2,200,Data002` followd by `ABC1,100,Data001`.

Comment: @Mithrandir - Nope. I am not getting the expected result in SQL Server.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Hi Roms , Really very nice question many of Database Guys always mistake with this. please refer my answer it will help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server has no any sense to populate by default order by. 
In your inner query you have not specified order by so it returned wrong result. 
Now use below code for SQL Server 2008 R2

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Configuration ORDER BY 1) AS a ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

One other alternative is : Comman Table Expression , Like below,

```
;WITH cteTest AS
(
    SELECT TOP 2 * 
    FROM Configuration ORDER BY 1
)
SELECT * FROM cteTest ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Comment: Thank you any for Answer.
But I will not mark it as Accepted because I wanted the reason why SQL manipulates execution in this way.
And also you mentioned that "SQL Server has no any sense to populate by default order by", 
it has default ascending "order by".

For eg.

Select top 2 T.* from (
select 'Data5' as c1
union 
select 'Data3'
union 
select 'Data4' 
union 
select 'Data2' 
union 
select 'Data1' 
union 
select 'Data6' ) T

It will give 

c1
-----
Data1
Data2

Comment: Roms, SQL will process the query base on good performance path , I agree with you that by default order by clause is ascending but SQL will decide that on which column it should be apply .
SQL Server many time return different result on different environment it automatically check good path for execution so if you want to select top 2 data base on ascending order then you have to 
specify that otherwise it will take base on good execution path so now This answer is accepted right ?